# How to change the stdout and stderr Task files directory?

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

In Linux, spring-cloud-dataflow local server logs for Task executions is /tmp/spring-cloud-dataflow-*. I need these task-specific directories to be created somewhere else, not /tmp.

E.g. instead of 
/tmp/spring-cloud-dataflow-{number}/{task-name}-{number}/{task-name}-{uuid}

Have it at:
/opt/myapp/logs/spring-cloud-dataflow-{number}/{task-name}-{number}/{task-name}-{uuid}

How can I configure this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override that via: `spring.cloud.deployer.local.workingDirectoriesRoot` property. See docs [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-application-configuration).